# Proper way to implement CoreBluetooth connectPeripheral timeout?

Tags: ios, ios8, core-bluetooth

Given that bluetooth seems to be good about timing out connections when one end goes off, I thought that the `CBCentralManager connectPeripheral:options:` method would automatically timeout if it couldn't connect after a certain time (because maybe I had turned off/reset the target peripheral in the interim between when I had scanned it and when the user selected it to connect).

I looked at the `options` argument for a possible timeout parameter, but no such luck.

Is the correct technique to startup an `NSTimer` that eventually fires a `cancelPeripheralConnection:` if the timer expires, and `invalidate` the timer in `centralManager:didConnectPeripheral:` and friends?

Comment: The short answer is if you want connection attempts to timeout then you need to build this yourself with a timer as you suggested.

Comment: Thanks. You should make that a real answer. :)

Comment: @TravisGriggs Did you figure this out? I'm also looking for the optimal way to do it. One way to do it would be to check the RSSI value of the peripheral in the function. If the strength of the signal is too low, you could time out the process.

Comment: checking RSSI requires a connection to the device, a timer is the only way that is reliable.

Comment: @Jobs and RSSI does not help when connection gets stuck for unknown reason - I have experienced this in experiments with Android based peripherals. IPhone just sits there waiting for connection success / failure event but it does not come, until the Android peripheral is completely shut down. So, sometimes a brute force timeout is the only way to recover - start scanning again and reconnect to the peripheral.

Answer (score -1):

Please, check the Apple documentation foro CBCentralManager and its method connectPeripheral:options:. First thing - attempts to connect to a peripheral do not time out, second thing - you may set delegate to receive connect/disconnect notifications.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CBCentralManager/connectPeripheral:options:

Comment: Do you think I would be able to reference the CBCentralManager methods as well as its delegate methods, as well as describe a scenario where a connect attempt spins infinitely, if I hadn't both read the documentation quite a bit, as well as implemented something?